# WASD movement in unity2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm new to unity and wanted to know how can i set the <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> keys to move me `right` and `left` with `Rigidbody2D`. I found this script on a forum but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public float speed = 5f;
private float movement = 0f;
private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if (movement > 0f)
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    else if (movement < 0f)
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * speed, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
    else
    {
        rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidBody.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: - improving demonstration of key presses
- removing white spaces in codes
- adding more tags to be accessible and seen by more people

Comment: Take a look at the `Input.GetKeyDown()` method, should do what you need.

Comment: What does not work? Is there an error, does the player not move at all, or does the player move incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an error being thrown?
First thing to check is that whatever you have attached this script to actually has a `Rigidbody2D`.

Physics, ie setting rigidbody speeds, should be done in `FixedUpdate` rather than `Update`, if you look that up and it seems too confusing right now don't worry, you can get away with this for now.

Perhaps you should try using `rb.AddForce(movement * speed, ForceMode2D.Impluse);`.

Since the var `movement` will actually be positive or negative depending on what key you press, the first two bits of the if statements don't have any use.

Try out looking at [this](https://github.com/DerekCresswell/GameDesign11/blob/master/3%20Top%20Down%20Arcade/2%20PlayerInput.md) for a single tutorial about moving the player.